# how to get data from an html5 form without using php in phonegap

Tags: html, cordova

have to design an app in phonegap using html5 in which some data has to be collected from the form and is stored in a database.
the question is that how can i get that data from the form without using php and the 'post' method..??
suppose the user has to login before proceeding, now how can i get the username and password from the form and match it to the database. The problem is not of

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap is full javascript api. You won't have a system with html form sending request/response. 
You have to design your app in a way it is using services. Try to add some javascript library like [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) or just [jquery](http://jquery.com/) (like example below) to help you in your work. 
These libraries work fine with Phonegap (and sencha is the most optimized).

- Write your **service side** ; it could be just simple php pages that will handle form parameters like a standard html application. You need a server side somewhere to access the database ; so host this file on an php/apache somewhere it can be accessible to the application.

--

```
<?php 
   /* mySaveService.php */
   /* do something like $_GET['param1'] mysql_connect() / mysql_query() and all the stuff */
?>
```

--

- Design your **client's view side**, you can write the bare html code or use a framework like Sencha (cleaner and harder way).

--

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="param1" value="" />
  <input type="button" class="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

--

- Add a **listener** on your form submission or the submit-button click :

--

```
$('form .submit').click( function() {
  saveInDb($(this).parents('form:first'));
});
```

--

- Write a javascript function which sends an **ajax call** with your form's data. The url will not be in the same domain, be sure to allow cross-domain requests.

--

```
saveInDb = function($form) {   
  var myParams = array();   
  $form.find('input').each(function() {
    myParams[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); 
  });   
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://domain.com/mySaveService.php',
    data: myParams,
    success: myCallback
  });   
}
```

--

- Don't forget to write the callback function, to alert the user that
  everything went fine

--

```
myCallback = function() {
  alert('It works');
}
```

--

- Alternatively, if you don't need to gather all the form's data in one
  place, you could use directly [localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage).

I hope it'll help. Regards